# Ripple emulator support cookies

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

I am working on Blackberry Webworks Ripple Emulator. My application involves storing cookies and is not working on emulator. But it works on device.

I am not sure if Ripple emulator works with cookies or not.

Please confirm.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, Ripple does support cookies.  However it depends on whatever security settings you establish in the Chrome browser.  So if you have your cookie caching settings set to 'do not accept' then Ripple won't either.  Could that be the situation in your case?

Try loading this URL in Ripple and creating a cookie (from the Examples section at the bottom): http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: Ripple emulator is able to store cookies. But in my App, I get "Refused to get unsafe header "X-CSRF-Token" message in console.

Comment: "X-CSRF-Token" suggests the issue is related to a cross-origin request issue. If you are using a library like jQuery to do AJAX requests, it may be rooted in there.  Otherwise it could be related to Chrome security settings (any unique start up flags set with Chrome?).